# join list of boolean elements groovy

Tags: groovy, arraylist

i have a list of boolean elements:

```
  def list=[true,false,true,true]
```

i ask if exist method such as following :

```
  list.joinBoolean('&&')
```

< false

Because : true && false && true && true=false

```
list.joinBoolean('||')
```

< true

Because : true || false || true || true=true

if it does not exist , i know how to do the loop to get expected  result ;

**AND**

```
  boolean tmp=true;
  list.each{e->
     tmp=tmp && e;    
  }
   return tmp;
```

**OR**

```
  boolean tmp=false;
  list.each{e->
     tmp=tmp || e;    
  }
   return tmp;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or:

```
list.inject { a, b -> a && b }
list.inject { a, b -> a || b }
```

if `list` can be empty, you need to use the longer inject form of:

```
list.inject(false) { a, b -> a && b }
list.inject(false) { a, b -> a || b }
```

Or use the `any` and `every` methods below

---

#### Btw

The `any` and `every` functions mentioned in the other answers work like:

```
list.any()
list.every()
```

Or (longer form)

```
list.any { it == true }
list.every { it == true }
```

Comment: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Cannot call inject() on an empty collection without passing an initial value.

Comment: @AbdennourToumi So `list` is empty? `[]`?  What should happen then?

Comment: @AbdennourToumi if `list` can be empty, I'd use `list.any()` for `||` and `list.every()` for `&&`

Answer (score 4):

`any` and `every` methods can come handy here

Comment: +1 (I always forget about them), though `any` and `every` isn't it (not `all`)?

Comment: @tim_yates my bad, ruby has `any` and `all`, in groovy we have `any` and `every`. Correcting the answer. I should have checked doc before posting :)

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't such method. But you can do it without each looping:

```
def list=[true,false,true,true]
list.any{it==true} // will work as list.joinBoolean('||')
list.every{it==true} // will work as list.joinBoolean('&&')
```

Comment: That doesn't run `No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.all() is applicable for argument types`

Comment: yep, missed comparison